# IndexError: list index out of range while webscraping advertisements with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping my local site for apartments buying/ rental advertisments.

I'm receiving the IndexError: list index out of range error in some cases.

I receive the errors while my scraper encounters an add which doesn't have some of the parameters. Normally it's Powierzchnia ( size), Liczba pokoi(number of rooms), Pietro ( floor), Rok budowy(year of built - which i'm not scraping)

I think it's because of this:

```
pietro = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[2].text
```

if there is no [2] , which is normally the third parameter, it throws an error that this [2] is out of range.

I was trying to put an if into the for loop, which would check if there is such parameter and if not, go on. However couldn't get through it.

I also tried to use it like this:

```
Powierzchnia = zrzut.find_all('li', class_ = "list__item__details__icons__element details--icons--element--powierzchnia")[0].text
```

This one wasn't throwing an error, but gave the same size to all of the addvertisments

Here's the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
link = 'https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci/wi,100,dw,1d.html?' + str(strona)
r = get(link, headers = headers)
zupa = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

ogloszenia= zupa.find_all('div', class_="list__item")

n_stron = 0
numer = 0
for strona in range(0,12):
    n_stron +=1
    for ogl in ogloszenia:
        tytul = ogl.find_all('h2', class_ ="list__item__content__title")[0].text
        powierzchnia = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[0].text
        liczba_pokoi = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[1].text
        pietro = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[2].text
        lokalizacja = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__content__subtitle")[0].text
        cena = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__price__value")[0].text
        cena_m = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__details__info details--info--price")[0].text

        numer += 1
        print(numer)
        print(tytul)
        print('Powierzchnia: ' + powierzchnia )
        print('Lokalizacja: ' + lokalizacja )
        print('Liczba pokoi: ' + liczba_pokoi )
        print('Pietro: ' + pietro )
        print('Cena: ' + cena )
        print('Cena za metr kwadratowy: ' + cena_m +'\n')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the `IndexError` exception and set the variable to `None` or `''`

```
try:
    powierzchnia = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[0].text
except IndexError:
    powierzchnia = ''
```

You might encounter this for other variables as well. Just repeat the same for each.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two changes.

First, try isolating the repeating commands in a function.

```
def findDetail(ogl, tag, class, index):
     return ogl.find_all(tag, class_ = class)[index].text
```

Then, in the cases where an index is not available, you can handle it with a “try-except”. This is the standard way to handle errors in Python:

```
def findDetail(ogl, tag, class, index):
    try:
        return ogl.find_all(tag, class_ = class)[index].text
    except IndexError:
        print(f”Could not find index {index} for {tag} with {class}”)
        return “”
```

Then call it with:

```
for ogl in ogloszenia:
    tytul = findDetail(ogl, “h2”, “"list__item__content__title", 0)
    powierzchnia = findDetail(ogl, ‘p’, "list__item__details__icons__element__desc", 0)
```

And so on. If the index can’t be found then it will just print a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")
for idx,entry in enumerate(data):
    if idx == 0:
        print('powierzchnia {}'.format(entry.text))
    elif idx == 1:
        print('liczba_pokoi {}'.format(entry.text))
    else:
        print('pietro {}'.format(entry.text))
```